# Pandas: Convert List Comprehension to Use Apply

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I currently have a Pandas DataFrame with a `beautiful_soup` column (it contains a `BeautifulSoup` object).  I want to add a column for several HTML tags (e.g. the number of `img` tags).

For instance, this is my old code using a list comprehension:

```
df['text_img_count'] = [len(x.find_all('img')) for x in df['beautiful_soup']]
```

But using `apply` should be faster, so I wanted to convert this code.

I was thinking of writing a small function that I could pass into `apply`, something like:

```
def get_imgs_count():
```

And then I'd call it like this:

```
df['text_img_count'] = df['beautiful_soup'].apply(get_imgs_count)
```

Since I'm going to be doing this for a bunch of HTML tags, I don't really want to write a ton of super similar functions.  Would prefer writing something like:

```
def get_tag_count(df, tag)
```

And then call it like this:

```
get_tag_count(df, 'img')
```

But I don't think I can pass a function with arguments to `apply`...

How might I go about converting from list comprehension to using `apply`?

Thanks!

Comment: "But using apply should be faster, " why would you think that? Indeed, I am willing to be that an equivalent list-comprehension will be faster than `.apply`

Comment: Indeed, if *speed* is what you wan't, you've already shot yourself in the foot using `dtype=object`

Comment: In any event, you *can* pass arguments to the function you pass to `.apply`, use the [`args`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) keyword in the `.apply` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `functools`' partial application

```
from functools import partial
def get_tag_count(bs, tag):
    return [len(x.find_all(tag)) for x in bs]

get_image_count = partial(get_tag_count, tag = 'img')

df['text_img_count'] = df['beautiful_soup'].apply(get_image_count)
```

Comment: No need for `partial`, `.apply` already can handle arguments to the `func`